# The strings.xml file in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, string

An Android noob here.

So, I was following [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html) guide by Lars Vogel (section 20). I started a new Android Application Project in Google's modified Eclipse, and edited the strings.xml, so it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Temperature Converter</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <color name="myColor">#F5F5F5</color>
    <string name="celsius">to Celsius</string>
    <string name="fahernheit">to Fahrenheut</string>
    <string name="calc">Calculate</string>

</resources>
```

(The first 3 strings are default)

I then added a `TextView` to the activity_main.xml using the Graphical Layout. I tried to change the text property of the `TextView` using the Graphical Layout. For some the new strings I have added do not show up in the Resource Chooser.

I can only choose between the 3 default strings. but the strings.

Why?

(I tried using the text xml editor as well. It didn't work.)

Thanks!

Comment: remove the color element, clean and rebuild your project. If you want colors element, you have to create a file named colors inside values

Comment: @blackbelt `color` is not the problem. Both colors and strings are value resources and can be in any .xml file in res/values dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried Cleaning

```
   (Project > Clean )
```

and then Rebuild your project ?

```
  ( Project > Build Project)
```

Answer (score 2):

first thing, you have a color tag in your strings.xml. it doesn't belong there.

if it doesn't help to remove it:

- try to save all your files
- clean your project
- make sure you don't have any compilation errors
- make sure you reference the strings this way:

  ```
  android:text="@string/calc"
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include surrounding tags, so that android recognises it, and as your resources.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Temperature Converter</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="celsius">to Celsius</string>
    <string name="fahernheit">to Fahrenheut</string>
    <string name="calc">Calculate</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: I checked the actual question by "editing" it, and he did include those tags, just they didn't show in his question. I formatted his question correctly. But you are right in what you say, so +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

As blackbelt pointed out, try to remove the "color" entry and see if it works. Probably is preventing the XML parser to see the other strings entry. And , of course, check that the entire XML file sintaxis is correct.